# How can I port a closed-source application based on OS X to Linux?

Tags: linux, macos, cross-platform, porting

How can I port an application based on OS X to Linux? It is closed source and working in Windows either. It is not wrriten in Objective C and doesn't use Cocoa.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could provide more details about the application. Is it a gui desktop, a daemon, what does it do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you saying that application working in Windows, so the easiest way is to use [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/download) to get start it on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it being closed source has any effect on porting it to Linux - it's the same anyway.

Just find alternatives to any win32-specific libraries or use a compatibility layer as necessary. Your team may however need to think very carefully about which distros they choose to support.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy path if you don't gave the source code as there are few Mac emulators.  You might have some luck get OSX to run under a VM but Apple frowns upon that.

In the end it sounds like a ground up rebuild.